# iBeacon: When to stop monitoring beacon in region

Tags: ibeacon

I built working iBeacon app where beacons getting monitored and ranging correctly, the work flow for now is like this

1. Monitor
2. Check event ENTER/EXIT
3. ranging a beacon entered or exited a region

However I would like to know when to stop monitoring and ranging a beacon !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For most apps, there is no reason to ever stop either monitoring or ranging.**  The main reason people think they need to do so is to conserve battery. But iOS CoreLocation and the Android Beacon Library automatically put limits on beacon scanning when apps are in the background to keep battery use in check.

Unless your app is designed to be kept running in the foreground for an extended period of time, or it takes extra measures to extend background ranging time, there is usually no reason to limit ranging.  Most of my apps start both monitoring and ranging at startup and never stop.

Of course, there are use cases where you simply do not want to get beacon discovery callbacks any more, so if this applies to your app then by all means turn off ranging and Monitoring as appropriate.

Comment: Hi! I checked each platform limits thank you for the great answer however, since you mentioned your way of building apps with beacon technology, I do not start ranging beacon until it Enter or Exit a region is that correct or I should start ranging when the app start like the monitoring !

Comment: Either way will work.  You won't range any beacons until you enter a region, so there is no logical reason to start sooner.  But It is less complex to code the app so you just start ranging and monitoring at the same time.  Since there is no significant performance hit to doing so, you might as well keep things simple and start both at the same time.

Comment: I range after Entering or Exiting event to get the proximity. Is there other way to get the proxmity! also as you mentioned to not start ranging when not needed.

Comment: Ranging is the only way to get proximity, yes.  It is generally OK to start ranging whenever convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop monitoring for a beacon when the task for the beacon is completed for the day/period.

*For example:*
A user enters the beacon region, you send a notification and your task is done. If the same user exits the region and enters again, you don't wanna bug them with multiple notifications. Hence you stop monitoring for a day or a particular amount of time.